# Incorrect information about JsonNullable in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui

I use JsonNullable in a project and the following dependencies.

```
<swagger-parser.version>2.1.13</swagger-parser.version>
<jackson-databind-nullable.version>0.2.6</jackson-databind-nullable.version>
<openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>7.0.0</openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>
```

But the generated docs available at http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
seem to miss some information about `JsonNullable`

Below is an excerpt from it:

```
...
"JsonNullableString": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "present": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    "description": "Some description",
    "example": 252534342
},
"OrganizationUpdateData": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "inn": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JsonNullableString"
        },
        "kpp": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JsonNullableString"
        },
...
```

it can be seen that `JsonNullable` doesn't have a value, but only a flag that indicates whether it has one or not.

I noticed that backend part works fine and can differentiate between received null or absent value. So if I start the service and use in some request to it:

```
{
inn: null
}
```

it is deserialized as `JsonNullable.of(null)`

if `inn` isn't contained in request json at all it will be deserialized as `JsonNullable.undefined()`

But frontend developers have difficulties with generation of code that would allow them to build requests.

Not sure what needs to be done to solve their problem. And I don't even understand how the "right" contents of
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
should look like...

I define the structure using OpenApi 3.0.3 in `organization.yml`

```
openapi: 3.0.3

info:
  title: Organization API
  description: Organization operations
  version: '1.0.0'

...

    OrganizationUpdateData:
      type: object
      description: Organization update data
      properties:
        inn:
          type: string
          nullable: true
          description: inn
          example: 2395318535
          pattern: "^(\\d{10}|\\d{12})$"

...
```